# Aymptotic analysis for Following fucntions

Tags: asymptotics

Below is an excercise from algorithm design manual

For each pair of expressions (A,B) below, indicate whether A is O, o, Ω, ω, or
Θ of B. Note that zero, one or more of these relations may hold for a given pair;
list all correct ones.

A  -------           B  
(a)$ n^{100}$   $2^n$ 
(b)$(lgn)^12$   √n     
(c)√n           $n^{cos(πn/8)}$
(d) $10^n        100^n$ 
(e) $n^{lg n}        (lg n)n$

I can tell which is the dominating function but I am finding difficulty in proving the exact 
bound for example I know for a $2^n$ >> $ n^{100}$ but is it O or o.Can someone please help me?

Comment: For the functions in your example: take $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^{100}}=0$. Hence $n^{100}=o(2^n)$ or $2^n=\omega(n^{100})$